# Filtering rows by column value

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have this simple d-fn in Dyalog:

`{⍺,≢⍵} ⌸  'koala'`

, which returns:

```
k 1
o 1
a 2
l 1
```

I want to filter rows from the resulting array, so that (for example, for filter value=2), I would get:

```
a 2
l 1
```

In general, I would like to know how to operate on n-th column of a 2D array in APL.

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, could you pls. accept it (tick the ckeckmark next to the reply), so that the question is no longer shown as `Open`.?
If it didn't answer, can you pls. refine the question?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected answer also shows you'd like to see the row with l/1 - is that right?

Assuming you're really after rows where the 2nd columns =2, you could filter with another dfn:

```
      {(⍵[;2]=2)⌿⍵}{⍺,≢⍵} ⌸  'koala'
a 2
```

As for the general part of the question, I hope the use of indexing `[;2]` answers the question, otherwise I'd need some more words ;-)